# Tablesorter scroller widget - prevent scroll to top on window resizeEnd

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I noticed that a tablesorter with the `scroller` widget will scroll to the top of the table when the window is resized. Unfortunately I have another plugin that occasionally triggers a resize event (a [modal](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/6018) for those curious).

So whenever the modal opens my table scrolls to the top. Is there a way I could prevent this?

Comment: There is a [`scroller_upAfterSort` widget option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-scroller.html#scroller-up-after-sort) which is enabled by default. But it appears that disabling it still causes this problem. I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/1458) and I'll try to get to it soon.